# Prefetching imports in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

today i was browsing internet and i found that html import can have `rel` attribute with `prefetch` value.

Well, since polymer is only about imports, there is a question. Should i use prefetch, when dynamically loading imports ? In my project i am using Polymer.Base.importHref which i don't know how works. This prefetch imports save file in cache for future use, but do polymer import load this file from cache? does it invoke that prefetch or does it load file without looking into that cache?

And the last question, is it even usefull? does it speed up site or improve some performance?

Comment: Be aware of certain limitations on `prefetch`. I think IE only prefetches 10 or so links and ignores the rest. Also, load only what you really need for the first paint and then lazy load everything else. I think this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVVOGnlOAX0) video covers most of it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The video you have posted i already saw earlier, but it doesn't answer my questions at all. Of course i am using page.js same as in video and i am lazy loading dependencies. I just wanted to know some opinions about this prefetch value since i have never seen it before

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this [medium article](https://medium.com/@soorajchandran/speeding-up-your-website-using-prefetching-techniques-8077058b7418) that explains the different prefetch & pre-render options. It doesn't necessarily answers your question, but it does shed some light on that whole subject.

**Regarding the Polymer importHref:**
I don't think adding prefetch parameters to the importHref will have any effect however, this is just an assumption I am making from reading the dox's.

> This method creates a new `<link rel="import">` element with the provided URL and appends it to the document to start loading.

From my understanding this would overwrite any set `rel=""`
But as far as I know the importHref doesn't load resources that have been loaded already so it might be looking into the cache.